# How to combine rows into one column based on boolean values in Google Sheets?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas

I'm having a hard time wrapping my mind around how to approach this...

Say I have a table with several items with different potential properties, which are assigned a boolean value for each property for each item. (in this case we have several options for each "color" and "size")

```
            |           Color                  |       Size     
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Item    | Red | Blue | White | Black | Tan | Large | Medium | Small
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Pants   |     | y    |       | y     | y   | y     | y      | y    |
    Shirt   | y   |      | y     | y     |     | y     | y      | y    |
    Skirt   |     | y    | y     |       |     |       | y      | y    |
    Socks   | y   | y    | y     | y     | y   | y     | y      | y    |
```

And I want to then output this into a single column like:

```
Pants, Blue, Large
Pants, Blue, Medium
Pants, Blue, Small
Pants, Black, Large
Pants, Black, Medium
Pants, Black, Small
Pants, Tan, Large
Pants, Tan, Medium
Pants, Tan, Small
Shirt, Red, Large
etc etc
```

So, I'm trying to populate a column with all the possible results of the true values for each row, concatenated with the header for each column that has a true value. In this example, it would further break out color and size for each item.

Thoughts on the best approach to this in Google Sheets?

Example sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/199msbUtUuZzb0HvBMgjQW98hRt3StFEyUFfTfLzSQzw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: answer: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/125018/186471

Comment: Thanks for sharing this previous answer also. I was able to get this to work, but needed to add one more step to concatenate the columns into one. Your custom answer below solved that too.

Comment: There's a hidden formula I recently discovered called =FLATTEN().  It makes these kinds of problems much simpler.  Happy to demo on your sample sheet.  Can you make it editable?

Comment: Sure, sounds great thanks MattKing!

Comment: So, i hadn't realized there were actually TWO datatables that needed retabulation (color and size).  so Flatten() won't work. I do have another method that might be a little easier to work with, and I'll post it up.

Comment: My original answer had a typo that I have since fixed.

Comment: @MattKing now I am curious about FLATTEN where its hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on a small scale:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("\", 1, 
 IF(B3:F6="y", REPT(A3:A6&", "&B2:F2&"\", MMULT(N(G3:I6="y"), 
 TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(G2:I2)^0))), )), "\"))&", "& 
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(" ", REPT(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(G3:I6="y", G2:I2, )),, COLUMNS(IF(G3:I6="y", G2:I2, )))))&" ", 
 MMULT(N(B3:F6="y"), TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B3:F6)^0)))), " ")))
```

[image: 0]

---

for just combo of two:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 IF(B3:F="y", "♦"&A3:A&", "&B2:F2&"♦", ),,99^99)),,99^99), "♦")), 
 "where not Col1 starts with ' ' order by Col1"))
```

[image]

---

**modded @MK formula to mimic CSV:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(4*5*3, 1, 0)/(5*3)+3, 
 {ROW(A:A), A:A&",", IF(B:I="y", {B2:F2&",", G2:I2}, )},
 INT(MOD(SEQUENCE(4*5*3, 1, 0), {9^99, 5*3, 3})/{9^99, 4, 1})+{2, 3, 3+4}),
 "where Col2<>'' and Col3<>''")),,9^99)))
```

Comment: Well, that's perfect! Thanks!

Comment: So I'm having a bit of trouble deciphering what is going on with the numerous SPLIT/TEXTJOIN/REPT/MMULT functions. For example, I wanted to experiment with a single set of properties. In this case, say, just colors (dropping the size options completely), but cant quite get that to work. Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: for just **ITEM × COLOR** you can do: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmWzJ.png

Comment: Thank you player0! I can see that the single property is a lot different approach than when adding more properties to iterate through. Works perfectly.

Comment: @MattG answer updated with MattKing's formula to simulate CSV if you need it in one column

Answer (score 1):

For problems like these, I like to use a VLOOKUP() with an [index] value that is made up of an array constructed out of some of the parameters of your data.  I made a new tab called mK.Help and put this formula there which will retabulate your data into the way you're hoping (i think).

If you definitely want comma separated, I can help with that, but usually folks just want the data in columns.  each of the parameters is fed by a simple formula counting the various aspects of your data.  The big reorganizing formula can be rewritten to include each of those formulae instead of referring to a helper cell, but I have found that it is easier for folks to understand what's going on when I leave it broken out like that.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(Q3*Q4*Q5,1,0)/(Q4*Q5)+Q2,{ROW(A:A),A:A,IF(B:I="y",B2:I2,)},INT(MOD(SEQUENCE(Q3*Q4*Q5,1,0),{9^99,Q4*Q5,Q5})/{9^99,Q5,1})+{2,3,3+Q4}),"where Col2<>'' and Col3<>''"))
```

Comment: I've updated the formula.  Thanks @player0 for flagging the mistake.